# R terra: rolling sum across layers

Tags: r, r-raster, rolling-computation, terra

Having a large stack of timeserie rasters I would like to create another rasterstack which represents  5-day rolling sum per each pixel across the layers. Given the size of the raster stack, the `raster::calc` runs endlessly for this task, and I was therefore wondering if this operation could be implemented faster using the `terra::lapp`. However:

```
library(terra)
stack_A<-rast(nlyrs=10)
rollsum<-function(x){data.table::frollsum(x,n=5)}

stack_B<-lapp(stack_A, fun=rollsum)
```

returns an error:

```
"Error in (function (x)  : 
  unused arguments (c(0, 0,...

or: [lapp] I do not like 'fun' :("
```

Id be gratefull if somebody could suggest where the mistake is, or maybe suggest another implementation (`stars::`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `terra::app` for that; `terra::app` is equivalent to `raster::calc`. You tried `terra::lapp`, that method is equivalent to `raster::overlay`.

```
library(terra)
library(data.table)
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(c(f,f,f,f))
rollsum <- function(x){data.table::frollsum(x,n=5)} 

x <- app(r, rollsum)
```

I am not sure if this will be much faster, as the bottleneck probably is the rollsum function.

"terra" has a function `roll` for this and I expect that to be much faster.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.47
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(c(f,f,f,f))
y <- roll(r, 5, "sum", type="to")
```

Comment: Many thanks @RobertHijmans, the terra::roll function did it in a much faster way indeed